# Trust anchor for certification path not found in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: ssl-certificate, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I have been using the Microsoft Graph API in my android application to get the calendar events etc...
The Authentication and events data retrieval were all working fine, but Microsoft Graph is not working properly on devices under 4.4 lately, when I try to get user data or calendar events, an exception occurs.
I run the same codes on 2 android SDK versions, on 6.0, I can get all the data I want but on 4.4, it fails with the exception :

**Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

Please suggest solutions for resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you using Java SDK or Microsoft graph SDK for Android?

Comment: I tested with latest Graph SDK and it works. So this looks like a certificate trust issue or older Graph SDK you might be using, not from Graph API/SDK end. If you're using older Graph API/SDK, upgrade to the latest, test and see still if you're facing the issue or not.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I am using Microsoft Graph SDK for android